# Regex Nth match or Last Match if < N matches

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the nth match, or the last match if there are fewer than n.  n is determined within my program and the regex string is constructed with 'n' replaced by an integer.

Here is my best guess, but my repetition operator {1,n} is always matching just once.  I thought it would be greedy by default

```
The basic regex would be:
distinctiveString[\s\S]*?value="([^"]*)"

So I modified it to this to try to get the nth one instead
(?:distinctiveString[\s\S]*?){1,n}value="([^"]*)"

distinctiveString randomStuff value="val1"
moreRandomStuff
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val2"
moreRandomStuff
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val3"
moreRandomStuff
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val4"
moreRandomStuff
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val5"
```

So in this case what I want is with n = 2 I'd get 'val2', n = 5 I'd get 'val5', n = 8 I would also get 'val5'.

I'm passing my regular expression through an application layer, but I think it's being handed directly to Perl as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(?:(?:[\s\S]*?distinctiveString){4}[\s\S]*?|(?:[\s\S]*distinctiveString)[\s\S]*?)value="([^"]*)"
```

which would have `"val4"` in match group 1 or `"val3"` for the input:

```
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val1"
moreRandomStuff
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val2"
moreRandomStuff
distinctiveString randomStuff value="val3"
```

A quick break down of the pattern:

```
(?:                                         #
  (?:[\s\S]*?distinctiveString){4}[\s\S]*?  # match 4 'distinctiveString's
  |                                         # OR
  (?:[\s\S]*distinctiveString)[\s\S]*?      # match the last 'distinctiveString'
)                                           #
value="([^"]*)"                             #
```

By looking at your profile, it seems you are most active in the Java tag, so here a  small Java demo:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    private static String getNthMatch(int n, String text, String distinctive) {
        String regex = String.format(
                "(?xs)                 # enable comments and dot-all           \n" +
                "(?:                   # start non-capturing group 1           \n" +
                "  (?:.*?%s){%d}       #   match n 'distinctive' strings       \n" +
                "  |                   #   OR                                  \n" +
                "  (?:.*%s)            #   match the last 'distinctive' string \n" +
                ")                     # end non-capturing group 1             \n" +
                ".*?value=\"([^\"]*)\" # match the value                       \n",
                distinctive, n, distinctive
        );
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
        return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val1\" \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val2\"       \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val3\"       \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val4\"       \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val5\"         ";

        String distinctive = "distinctiveString";

        System.out.println(getNthMatch(4, text, distinctive));
        System.out.println(getNthMatch(5, text, distinctive));
        System.out.println(getNthMatch(6, text, distinctive));
        System.out.println(getNthMatch(7, text, distinctive));
    }
}
```

which will print the following to the console:

```
val4
val5
val5
val5
```

Note that the `.` matches the same as `[\s\S]` when the dot-all option (`(?s)`) is enabled.

### EDIT

Yes, `{1,n}` *is* greedy. However, when you place `[\s\S]*?` *after* `distinctiveString` in `(?:distinctiveString[\s\S]*?){1,3}`, then `distinctiveString` is matched and then reluctantly zero or more chars (so zero will be matched) which is then repeated between 1 and 3 times. What you want to do is move `[\s\S]*?` *before* `distinctiveString`:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

        private static String getNthMatch(int n, String text, String distinctive) {
            String regex = String.format(
                    "(?:[\\s\\S]*?%s){1,%d}[\\s\\S]*?value=\"([^\"]*)\"",
                    distinctive, n
            );
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
            return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String text = "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val1\" \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val2\"       \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val3\"       \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val4\"       \n" +
                "moreRandomStuff                                    \n" +
                "distinctiveString randomStuff value=\"val5\"         ";

        String distinctive = "distinctiveString";

        System.out.println(getNthMatch(4, text, distinctive));
        System.out.println(getNthMatch(5, text, distinctive));
        System.out.println(getNthMatch(6, text, distinctive));
        System.out.println(getNthMatch(7, text, distinctive));
    }
}
```

which also prints:

```
val4
val5
val5
val5
```

Comment: Any idea why {1,n} doesn't match n if it can?  I thought regular expressions were generally greedy by default.

Comment: @Mike, good point. I made it all far too complicated. Will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: So the non-greediness of the \*? inside the grouping I applied {1,n} breaks the greediness of that operator.  Very interesting.  I find myself making things non-greedy more often than not because greedy seems more brittle/dangerous.  I think your answer gives me a glimpse of a more general rule that non-greedy operators need to have specific following patterns to force them to expand, otherwise they are brittle too.  They can just disappear and match nothing.  Greedy operators aren't dangerous if you give them a good guard, like ("[^"]*") can't match the whole file, it's boxed in by the quote.